# HTML is not decoded in email message

Tags: opencart

I am using email sending code in opencart but in email message html is not decoded 
and my code is

```
                $email_message = "<table>";
                $email_message .= "<td><h1>Congratulations!</h1></td>";
                $email_message .= "<td>"."Valued Customer,"."</td>";
                $email_message .= "<td>Message</td>";
                $email_message .= "</table>";

                $email_to =  $this->request->post['subscribe_email'];
                $mail = new Mail();

                $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
                $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
                $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
                $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
                $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');            
                $mail->setTo($email_to);
                $mail->setFrom("xyz@xyz.com");
                $mail->setSender("xyz@xyz.com");
                $mail->setSubject("Congratulations!");
                $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($email_message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

                $mail->send();
```

please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:
`$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($email_message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));`

to:

`$mail->setHtml($email_message);`

Have a nice day :) !!

Comment: Thanks dear you save my time Sankar V

Answer (score 1):

Replace `setText` to `setHtml` and pass `$email_message` variable

$mail->setHtml($email_message);

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code that should work

```
            $email_message = "<html>";
            $email_message = "<body>";
            $email_message = "<table>";
            $email_message .= "<td><h1>Congratulations!</h1></td>";
            $email_message .= "<td>"."Valued Customer,"."</td>";
            $email_message .= "<td>Message</td>";
            $email_message .= "</table>";
            $email_message = "</body>";
            $email_message = "</html>";   

            $email_to =  $this->request->post['subscribe_email'];
            $mail = new Mail();

            $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
            $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
            $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
            $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
            $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
            $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
            $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');            
            $mail->setTo($email_to);
            $mail->setFrom("xyz@xyz.com");
            $mail->setSender("xyz@xyz.com");
            $mail->setSubject("Congratulations!");
            $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($email_message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

            $mail->send();
```